# Check if Field is of Type Rich Text with @Formula

Tags: lotus-notes, xpages

I need to check if a field is of type "Rich Text" using @Forumla in a View. How can I achieve this?
Alternatively, check the byte size of a field also using @Forumla in a View.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn Rich Text into plain text using the `@Abstract` formula, and then display *that* in the view.  Unfortunately @Abstract does not work in views.

If views themselves won't get the job done, you can always use an agent to process the documents and set a document item value, which in turn can be shown in a view.  It's an extra step but often can get the job done.  Using LotusScript you could loop through all the document's items and check if they are a RICHTEXT type, and then stamp the document with an "IsRichText" item set to "Yes", for example.

Answer (score 0):

Formula language will not show these values. The closes you can get is @Length. If it is possible in the design, calculate these values is a separate field using lotus script.